# How to lay out variable-number of panels?

Tags: plot, layout, julia

I am new to Julia, so I apologize if this is covered in documentation that I've not uncovered yet.

My goal is to find a way to create a multi-panel plot in which I do not know the number of panels until runtime. This is so a program that I'm writing can accept a commandline arg that indicates which plot panels the person wants, in the form of a string, e.g. `--plots=1,2` would indicate to plot panel types 1 and 2.  I am splitting the string and making an integer vector `[1,2]` from this.  But what I am hoping to do next is to have a block that says "is plot type 1 desired" and then plots it, and then does the same for a list of plot types.  I thought of creating figures `fig1`, etc., and then binding them together into `figures`, say, and then doing `plot(figures,layout=...)` but the types were wrong.

Should I be working with varargs?

Or maybe using `Expr`?

Or maybe `plot()` itself has a way to do this directly?  (I tried doing e.g. `plot(fig1, nothing, fig2)` but did not succeed ... and indeed I only found `nothing` though google searches.)

Again, I'm sorry if I'm not even expressing things properly.  Fortran/C/C++/python/R programmer here, trying to learn Julia :-)

Comment: What package are you using for plotting, or do you not know yet? I suggest if you don't know yet pick one (probably either Plots.jl or Makie) and refocus your question on that one. You could even ask multiple questions if you don't know which

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using `Plots.js`.